Dot at the endpoint of a line
(1) How can I modify the below answer by Jake so that I can modify the size or the color of the dot or the empty dot? (Something like [centero-,size=x, color=y].) (2) The size of the dot is dependent on the width of the line drawn; how to make it independent of that?

\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgflibrary{arrows}

\makeatletter
\pgfarrowsdeclare{center*}{center*}
{
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-.5\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.4pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.2\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{4.5\pgfutil@tempdima}
}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.4pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.2\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfqpoint{4.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{0bp}}{4.5\pgfutil@tempdima}
  \pgfusepathqfillstroke
}

\pgfarrowsdeclare{centero}{centero}
{
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-.5\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.4pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.2\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{4.5\pgfutil@tempdima}
}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.4pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.2\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfqpoint{4.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{0bp}}{4.5\pgfutil@tempdima}
  \pgfusepathqstroke
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[help lines] (-.1,-.1) grid (2.1,2.1);
   \draw[thick,-center*] (0,1.5) -- (1,.5);
   \draw[thin,centero-] (1,1.5) -- (2,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Maybe the arrows with parameters from https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/b622950cf4e3ef72c828465dc6464ecffd5c320d/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.meta.code.tex#L221 could be a starting point.

What's wrong with using the uptodate arrows.meta library, as seen in the other answer. You can then simply use arrow tip keys width, length and related.

The arrows.meta library makes this really quite easy.
You just set a length, the width is set to be equal to the length. And the sep is half the size which places the center of the circle on the specified points. You can also change the circles' line width via line width and line width' (where the latter would again allow it to make it dependent on the length and not on the line width). You can just use color or, as with TikZ, just the name of a color, you can also use fill=<color> to specify a different fill color.
Code
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
  /pgf/arrow keys/Centered Circle size/.style={length={#1}, width'=+0pt +1, sep=-.5*(#1)},
  Centered Circle/.tip={Circle[Centered Circle size=3.14159pt]},
  CC*/.tip={Centered Circle[    ]},
  CCo/.tip={Centered Circle[open]}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (-.1,-.1) grid (2.1,2.1);
\draw[thick,    -CC*] (0, 1.5) -- (1, .5);
\draw[thin,  CCo-   ] (1, 1.5) -- (2, .5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Arrow tips were not really designed for this purpose. Of course there are ways to modify tips to achieve your desired outcome, but this seems to be the job of a node. So a simple alternative would be to design a node:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    mydot/.style={draw, circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=3pt, #1},
    mydot/.default={}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines] (-.1,-.1) grid (2.1,2.1);
    \node[mydot={fill=orange, draw=blue, minimum width=5pt}](A) at (1,.5){};
    \node[mydot](B) at (1,1.5){};
    \draw[thick] (0,1.5) -- (A);
    \draw[thin] (B) -- (2,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

